# How to set var or function call from action to component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, action, react-redux-form

I have a method in my action which interacts with the server and due to the way it's set up :

```
function generateDoc(specs) {
    // Gen start !
    InterfaceCard.setState({ showhide: true });
    // loop :
    const promises = [];
    specs.forEach((spec) => {
        if (spec) promises.push(generateChain(spec));
    });
    // gen end!
    InterfaceCard.setState({ showhide: false });
}
```

can give me a start and and end to my Document generation.

I'd like to on `// Gen start !` and `// gen end!` place a call or a var modification that a component can receive.

(obviously my current `InterfaceCard.setState({ showhide: false });` do not work.)

"InterfaceCard" isn't even the component grouped with this action file. This is actually the action of it's child (but that's fine. If I have to use props to make my way back up once I've at least finally reached the component associated with the current action, then I will, that's not really an issue.)

what bugs me is that I don't know a way to communicate back from an action to a component without use of a call to (and response from) a server.

forgive me the docs on this weren't to be found.

thanks!

UPDATE :

I'm at :

```
function generateDoc(specs) {
    show();
    const promises = [];
    specs.forEach((spec) => {
        if (spec) promises.push(generateChain(spec));
    });
    hide();
}

function show() {
    const pay = true;
    return dispatch => dispatch({ ...types.ALERT, pay });
}

function hide() {
    const pay = true;
    return dispatch => dispatch({ ...types.ALERTN, pay });
}
```

These do not dispatch. but if I do this :

```
function generateDoc(specs) {
    const promises = [];
    specs.forEach((spec) => {
        if (spec) promises.push(generateChain(spec));
    });
    const pay = true;
    return dispatch => dispatch({ ...types.ALERTN, pay });
}
```

the end dispatch does dispatch but it jumps over the code in the middle and omits it entirely.

so the first former looks better to me since (If I understand correctly) it allows me to have three returns in sequence.

the issue is they refuse to dispatch with that setup I dunno why.

UPDATE :

this worked:

```
function generateDoc(specs) {
    const promises = [];
    specs.forEach((spec) => {
        if (spec) promises.push(generateChain(spec));
    });
    return (dispatch) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(show());
        }, 1);
        setTimeout(() => {
            dispatch(hide());
        }, 9000);
    };
}

function show() {
    const pay = true;
    return { ...types.ALERT, pay };
}

function hide() {
    const pay = true;
    return { ...types.ALERTN, pay };
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with just `Promise.all(promises).then(() => InterfaceCard.setState({showhide: false}))` - aside from assumption that you can set state of a component - this should be your own state and passed via `<InterfaceCard show={this.state.showhide} />`

Comment: it really HAS to originate from the action with the setup I have looping on the multiple calls has to happen in the action and that's not my call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dispatch an action and in related reducer change some props.
Then in your component, you can listen to changes of these props by using shouldComponentUpdate or componentWillReceiveProps.

```
function show() {
  return { ...types.ALERT, pay }
}

function hide() {
  return { ...types.ALERTN, pay }
}

function generateDoc(specs) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(show());
    dispatch(hide());
  }    
}
```

Comment: that sounds good. but I'm not sure I understand can you give a code example in your answer concerning the different files.

Comment: I'm almost there (in implementing what you said) but I've no idea how to do a `dispatch` without a `return` and I can't do it with a return since there are two of them and I need the rest of the code to be read.

Comment: `this.dispatch({ ...types.ALERT });` ?

Comment: nope. that syntax gives an error when run. I only know this syntax : `return dispatch => dispatch({ ...types.ALERT });` but I can't use that because of the `return`. `dispatch({ ...types.ALERT });` can't work because in that case `dispatch` is undefined. the IDE and npm and ESLINT really don't help you out here.

Comment: use redux-thunk. you can dispatch an action from another action if you use redux-thunk or redux-saga

Comment: I already have redux-thunk in my project. I need code examples to understand. I managed to get a `return dispatch` to execute the problem is that it took priority over the main thing this function is supposed to do.

Comment: I added code example. Test it and let me know if it works.

Comment: that works but only for the show hides the middle code is ignored. plus another issue is: they get fired milliseconds apart. how can I induce artificial wait?

Comment: I tried several times and what gets dispatched varies. sometimes its the "hide" call that gets ignored and the middle code does actually fire. sometimes it's the show and hide and the middle code doesn't fire.

Comment: ok yeah I figured it out updated my Q with what worked for me you can copy-paste it into your post I'll mark it as answer and remove that edit from my Q. thank you! well done! :)

Comment: I'm glad to see the problem solved. I think no need to delete or copy your answer. I saw your code. using setTimeOut maybe not good for others. it's good to see both my answer and your working code to compare.

Comment: the issue though is you need to extract your 'specs.forEach' from the return or else half of the time it won't be executed.

Comment: ok I will edit my action and will show just how to dispatch an another action.